# Регулярка для замены определенной части стринга с помощью re.sub

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста заменить с помощью re.sub, определенную часть стринга на портал если это gmx, web. И hosting соответственно если это 1and1.

Примерные списки выглядит вот так:

```
bmReE@web.ch|smtp.web.ch:25|bmReE@web.ch|atTMfRKwdm9vRtJ
AqhuC@gmx.com|login.1and1.com:25|AqhuC@1und1.com|K4CHPkJT4AJKELg
vvvbbbbbb@gmx.com|UnusualPerfekt1!|www.gmx.net
fffrrrttt@faltenbalg.de|RfrfRf|webmailcluster.1and1.com
hhhtttppp@1and1.com.de|empty49|www.1and1.com
ppppssss@deliverdigital.com|Password1|contactmanager.web.delivermedia.local
```

Ожидаемый ответ:

```
bmReE@web.ch|portal|bmReE@web.ch|atTMfRKwdm9vRtJ
AqhuC@gmx.com|hosting|AqhuC@1und1.com|K4CHPkJT4AJKELg
vvvbbbbbb@gmx.com|UnusualPerfekt1!|portal
fffrrrttt@faltenbalg.de|RfrfRf|hosting
hhhtttppp@1and1.com.de|empty49|hosting
ppppssss@deliverdigital.com|Password1|portal
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде совсем просто:

```
repl_dict = { 'gmx': 'portal', 'web': 'portal', '1and1': 'hosting' }
repl = lambda m: '|'+repl_dict[m.group(1)]
result = re.sub( r'\|[^|]*\.(gmx|web|1and1)\.[^|\n]*', repl, text, flags=re.M )
```

Здесь

- `repl_dict` - словарь подстановок
- `repl` - функция подставляющая нужное значение на основе словаря.

Результат:

```
>>> text = """bmReE@web.ch|smtp.web.ch:25|bmReE@web.ch|atTMfRKwdm9vRtJ
AqhuC@gmx.com|login.1and1.com:25|AqhuC@1und1.com|K4CHPkJT4AJKELg
vvvbbbbbb@gmx.com|UnusualPerfekt1!|www.gmx.net
fffrrrttt@faltenbalg.de|RfrfRf|webmailcluster.1and1.com
hhhtttppp@1and1.com.de|empty49|www.1and1.com
ppppssss@deliverdigital.com|Password1|contactmanager.web.delivermedia.local"""
>>> import re
>>> repl_dict = { 'gmx': 'portal', 'web': 'portal', '1and1': 'hosting' }
>>> repl = lambda m: '|'+repl_dict[m.group(1)]
>>> result = re.sub( r'\|[^|]*\.(gmx|web|1and1)\.[^|\n]*', repl, text, flags=re.M )
>>> print( result )
bmReE@web.ch|portal|bmReE@web.ch|atTMfRKwdm9vRtJ
AqhuC@gmx.com|hosting|AqhuC@1und1.com|K4CHPkJT4AJKELg
vvvbbbbbb@gmx.com|UnusualPerfekt1!|portal
fffrrrttt@faltenbalg.de|RfrfRf|hosting
hhhtttppp@1and1.com.de|empty49|hosting
ppppssss@deliverdigital.com|Password1|portal
>>>
```

Comment: Внес исправления, измените, если не согласны.